# Where can I publish summaries of my research?

Tags: publications, computer-science, online-publication, reputation

I would like to publish summaries of my research in some news or research journal for the sake to promote the research. But there I don't want to publish anywhere but the summaries are also not so exciting to publish it in a prestigious journal. It is more to have a recognized online presence (url and doi) that is not the own homepage. What could I do?

Comment: Is there perhaps a suitable workshop in your field of research that has proceedings? If yes, you may want to check with the next workshop organizers if they are interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some quick ideas:

If you want to publish just short papers on single findings, there is a new journal called Matters which does just that. You will get a DOI. https://www.sciencematters.io/ Check the scope though, it may not be suitable for your discipline.

If you want to summarise your already published papers in order to reach a broader audience, something like Kudos could help. You won't get a DOI for these summaries, but will get metrics in a dashboard when you sign up and start writing summaries.

Finally, you could start blogging! It's a great way to document the research process. You can sign up for your own blog using WordPress or similar. You might have seen this Vox article recently on the researcher live-blogging her progress: http://www.vox.com/2016/3/3/11148452/science-blog
If you don't want to start your own blog, look for collective blogging platforms like Medium, or something specific to your discipline and start writing. The good thing about blogging is that the informality allows you to write a lot quicker. Promote your posts on social media to attract an audience.